# What does it mean if a stock skyrockets VWAP 10x aftermarket?

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-analysis

I just spotted $TSLA's VWAP skyrocket to 10k and go back down to 6k and still hanging there, I started trading like 8 months ago and I have never seen anything like this:

[image]

That is VWAP, not an actual quote price and couldn't quite see any odd sales in those times. What is a VWAP of 6-10x saying?, just trying to understand what happened.

P.S.: I understand that no answer qualifies as stock advice

Comment: Look up the formula for VWAP then look at the values of its inputs the day before it skyrocketed and their values the day that it skyrocketed.  Therein lies the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think it was Elon "paying back" to Tesla for his "transgressions"... he essentially owned the SEC.

https://mashable.com/article/elon-musk-sec-taunt/